# Routing path '/' to Component and highlighting menu item based on routerLinkActive

Tags: angular, url-routing

I've setup the following routes for `RouterModule` on `app.module.ts`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'inbox', component: InboxComponent },
  { path: 'report/request', component: RequestReportComponent },
  { path: 'report/create', component: CreateReportComponent },
  { path: '', component: InboxComponent }
])
```

And am printing out my menu with the following template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a [routerLink]="item.href">
            <i class="{{ item.iconClasses }}"></i>
            <span class="menu-item-key">
                {{ item.name }}
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

So, when I open the page with the default path `/`, it correctly maps to the default component, but the `<a>` tag highlighting won't work, because it probably expects it to match `/inbox` explicitly:

[image]

However, if I select the menu item that maps to `/inbox`, highlighting works as expected (and changes the url as well).

[image]

What's the recommended way to make this work? Is there any way out of the box to accomplish this or is any workaround necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'inbox' }
```

instead of

```
{ path: '', component: InboxComponent }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Is this strategy (redirecting to the component, ending up changing the url as well) the recommended practice with angular2 router?